# ExtJS gauge chart label not displaying

Tags: extjs4

The gauge is showing up just fine but the label "Some diff data" does not show up under the chart as expected. [Ext JS 4 API - Gauge](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.chart.series.Gauge) says *display* denotes how the label gets displayed. I assume title is the label. Any ideas?

```
series: [{
    type: 'gauge',
    field: 'diff1',
    donut: false,
    title: "Some diff data",
    display: 'under', //tried outside as well
    colorSet: ['#FFFFCC', '#FF9999']
 }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create text sprites for the title or any labels.

Look at the Ex.draw package.

Comment: im glad it solved ur problem..but it would be helpfull for others if u share ur solution ;)

Comment: Some of the options just don't work seemingly. I did add label as a sprite for a stacked bar chart for example but i am unable to use under, again. insideEnd and outside work but not under.

Comment: Although series has a display property as well, label display options work if you create a sprite for them like this:  `series: [{
                ....
                yField: ['start1','start2','start3','start4'],
                label: {
                  display: 'under',
                  field: ['name1','name2','name3','name4'],
                  orientation: 'horizontal',
                  color: '#333',
                  font: "20px Helvetica, sans-serif",
                  'text-anchor': 'middle'
                }
            }]`

Comment: you can edit your question and add the code, it would be displayed better

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the title field is for the title. But it's not specified as part of the series...it needs to be applied to the axes. Such as, like this:

```
    items: [{
        xtype: 'chart',
        data: 'data',
        height: 200,
        width: 200,
        animate: true,
        store: 'store1',
        axes: [{
            position: 'gauge',
            title: 'Your Title Here', // << HERE >>
            type: 'Gauge',
            margin: 8,
            maximum: 100,
            minimum: 0,
            steps: 4
        }],
        series: [{
            type: 'gauge',
            angleField: 'data1',
            donut: 60,
            needle: false
        }]
```